# crosstool config fail: panel library not found

Tags: crosstool-ng

When trying to configure crosstool-ng I run into error: panel library not found

```
...
...
checking for working ncursesw.h... no
checking for working ncurses.h... yes
checking for Curses Panel library with ncursesw/panel.h... no
configure: error: panel library not found
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

How do I get my hands on the 'Curses Panel Library'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per @asabxkh74142057:

crosstool-ng-1.25.0$ export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/ncursesw" crosstool-ng-1.25.0$ ./configure